# ASP.NET Web API 2 access current user claims via dependency injection with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

At the moment I have to develop a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API 2 with Topshelf and Owin.
I use Autofac as IOC container and an OAuth2 authentication with JWT tokens.

In .NET Core/.NET 5 web api's I can get DI access to the claims of the current user via `IHttpContextAccessor`.

How can I access the user claims via DI in my .NET Framework Web API using Autofac? (I don't want to access them in the API controller but in domain services).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Steven's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67618240/9888512) will work fine with normal .NET Web API 2 applications, it is not suitable for self-hosted applications with Owin, since `HttpContext.Current` is always `NULL` there.
Based on @Steven's suggested solution, I was able to solve the problem as follows:

Install the Nuget package [OwinRequestScopeContext](https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext).
Add `app.UseRequestScopeContext();` to the `Startup.cs`.
Add a `IClaimsProvider` interface to the Domain project:

```
public interface IClaimsProvider
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal UserClaims { get; }
    }
```

Add a `OwinContextClaimsProvider` class which implements `IClaimsProvider` to the startup project:

```
public class OwinContextClaimsProvider : IClaimsProvider
    {
        public ClaimsPrincipal UserClaims => OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Environment["server.User"] as ClaimsPrincipal;
    }
```

Register the ClaimsProvider using Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<OwinContextClaimsProvider>().As<IClaimsProvider>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Note: `IClaimsProvider.UserClaims` will be `NULL` if no user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

In your domain layer, create an abstraction tailed to that layer, allowing access to those details. Example:

```cs
public interface IClaimsProvider
{
   TheClaims Claims { get; }
}
```

In the startup path of the application, create an implementation of `IClaimsProvider` that uses the `HttpContext` to get this data. For instance:

```cs
public sealed class HttpContextClaimsProvider : IClaimsProvider
{
    public MyClaims Claims => // pull claims from HttpContext.Current
}
```

This implementation can be registered in Autofac as follows:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<HttpContextClaimsProvider>().As<IClaimsProvider>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, `HttpContext.Current` is always null.